# What means of transportation is used - "by trains"?

Tags: plural-forms, indian-english

> Is it safe to travel by *trains* in India?
>   Travelling by *train* in india is safe.

I know *by train* is correct. But it's confused to me whether it is correct or not using plural forms of the transportation when I saw above sentences in an English website. Likewise, is it correct to say by planes or by buses expressing how to get somewhere?

Comment: A quick survey of the Google hits shows that it seems to be used in Indian English, but it's not in American or British English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a native speaker of American English, and it definitely sounds a bit odd to me.  I don't think it's acceptable in my dialect, though it's possible that it's acceptable in others.

Still, take a look at [this graph](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=travel+by+train+%2F+travel+by+trains&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) from Google books n-grams:

[image: (travel by train / travel by trains)]

In this graph, you can see the proportion between *travel by train* and *travel by trains*.  By this measure, the former is almost a hundred times more common in today's English!  You can find similar results for [*travel by plane* versus *travel by planes*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=travel+by+plane+%2F+travel+by+planes&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and [*travel by car* versus *travel by cars*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=travel+by+car+%2F+travel+by+cars&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).  These seems to confirm that you should stick to the singular.

Let's verify this by looking at another corpus.  Take a look at the following results from [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

```
travel by train         26
travel by plane         12
travel by car           30
travel by trains        0
travel by planes        0
travel by car           0
```

Zero, zero, zero.  As expected, the plural forms are unattested.  Based on the above, I would stick to the singular form:

> Is it safe to travel **by train** in India?
>   Travelling **by train** in India is safe.

Some speakers might thinks it's acceptable to use the plural, but many won't, and you'll never go wrong with the singular.

Comment: Great answer :) I'm confused by the ngram though, I only see one line. Can you explain that please?

Comment: It's a proportion, A over B.  The `/` operator "divides the expression on the left by the expression on the right, which is useful for isolating the behavior of an ngram with respect to another."  Read more about ["Ngram compositions"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/info) on Google's help pages.

Comment: The plural is just possible (with a little effort!): *Avoid travelling by the trains in Katmandu, which are notoriously given to falling off the rails into thousand-foot abysses.*